# How to turn on the debugger button in Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, debugging, jupyter-lab

I am using jupyter lab and trying to embedd the `debugger` in it.

`Windows 10, 64 bit`

Here are the steps I followed:

```
conda create --name ml python=3.8.2
conda activate ml
conda install xeus-python notebook jupyterlab -c conda-forge

jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/debugger
```

Then I start `jupyter lab` and it opens in Google Chrome:

Though I get the debugger button in `xpython` notebook but I am not able to turn it on.
Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Can someone help how to turn on the debugger??

Comment: So the button is `unresponsive`? Have you tried restarting from anaconda navigator?

Comment: What dark theme are using, it may also interfere with it.

Comment: yes tried restarting...didn't help.

Comment: Try running it with the default theme or on another browser and see if it works

Comment: Checked with default theme also, still button is un-responsive. :(

Comment: Do you see any output in the console tab, in the inspect element?

Comment: did you manage to fix this issue? I have exactly the same issue

Answer (score 4):

A kernel with support for debugging is required to be able to use the debugger. Currently xeus-python is such a kernel, but the default IPython kernel will support the debugger soon too.

It is generally recommended to create a new conda environment to install the dependencies:

```
conda create -n jupyterlab-debugger -c conda-forge xeus-python notebook jupyterlab

conda activate jupyterlab-debugger
```

If running an old version of JupyterLab (2.x) you will also need to install `nodejs` to install the extension manually (note that it comes-preinstalled since JupyterLab 3.x so you do not need to run the commands below if using up-to date JupyterLab):

```
conda install nodejs
jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/debugger
```

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting that it may be to do with versioning issues or have not met the prerequisites. There are also no reported [similar issues](https://github.com/jupyterlab/debugger/issues) so it must be to do with your system.

Make sure you meet these

`JupyterLab 2.0+
xeus-python 0.7.1+
notebook 6+`

And also consider doing a fresh install of `Anaconda`. This fixes it in most cases.

Comment: I really can't tell where this could be going wrong. You can open an issue on GitHub and you will likely get help from the `contributors` of the library.

Comment: Yes, they updated the Read.me document. We need to install nodejs